# Jasmine mock window.location.reload(true);

Tags: jasmine, mocking, karma-jasmine, reload, window.location

I have a constructor of a js object that looks like this:

```
function SomeThing(window, document) {
   var self = this;
   self.window = window;
   self.document = document;

   if (!self.window.sessionStorage.getItem('page-reloaded')) {
      self.window.sessionStorage.setItem('page-reloaded', true);
      self.window.location.reload(true); // PROBLEM ON THIS LINE
      return;
   }
}
```

my mock test looks like this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  mockWindowObj = {
    'location': {
        'href': '',
        'search': '?hello=world',
        'pathname': '/some/path',
        'replace': function () {},
        'reload': jasmine.createSpy()
      }
   };

  spyOn(mockWindowObj.location, 'reload').and.callFake(function(){}); ;

  some = new SomeThing(mockWindowObj, mockDocumentObj);
});
```

When I run a test I get this error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
 {
   "message": "Some of your tests did a full page reload!",
   "str": "Some of your tests did a full page reload!"
 }
```

If I comment out the line `window.location.reload(true)` all of my test run fine and pass.  I'm sort of new to unit tests and I'm not sure how to get around this. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your posted code cannot be what you actually ran. The line containing `self.window.sessionStorage.getItem` would have to fail since you did not define sessionStorage on your mock.

I guess the SomeThing function is being called with window pointing to the real window object. That explains what you observe.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I just figured it out.  I was being an idiot and initiating the object at the bottom of the file.  So it ran the tests NOT seeing my mock object stoping the test in its tracks... ugh (derp on me).  

I was mocking sessionStorage on the object I just didn't post it on the question to keep it simple.